# Excluding a number of answers from a R dataframe

Tags: r, subset, na

I'm looking for a way to exclude a number of answers from a length function.
This is a follow on question from [Getting R Frequency counts for all possible answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784621/getting-r-frequency-counts-for-all-possible-answers) In sql the syntax could be

```
  select * from someTable
  where variableName not in ( 0, null )
```

Given

```
Id <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
ClassA <- c(1,NA,3,1,1)
ClassB <- c(2,1,1,3,3)
R <- c(5,5,7,NA,9)
S <- c(3,7,NA,9,5)
df <- data.frame(Id,ClassA,ClassB,R,S)

ZeroTenNAScale <- c(0:10,NA);

R.freq = setNames(nm=c('R','freq'),data.frame(table(factor(df$R,levels=ZeroTenNAScale,exclude=NULL))));
S.freq = setNames(nm=c('S','freq'),data.frame(table(factor(df$S,levels=ZeroTenNAScale,exclude=NULL))));

length(S.freq$freq[S.freq$freq!=0])

# 5
```

How would I change

```
length(S.freq$freq[S.freq$freq!=0])
```

to get an answer of 4 by excluding 0 and NA?

Comment: `length(S.freq$freq[S.freq$freq!=0 & !is.na(S.freq$S)])`?

Comment: If you could add that as an answer @procrastinatus-maximus I'll mark it as the selected answer. It looks more flexible than the other answers and allows for adding in further criteria easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `!is.na(S.freq$S)` as a second filter:

```
length(S.freq$freq[S.freq$freq!=0 & !is.na(S.freq$S)])
```

If you want to extend it with other conditions, you could make an index vector first for readability:

```
idx <- S.freq$freq!=0 & !is.na(S.freq$S)
length(S.freq$freq[idx])
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `colSums`,

```
colSums(!is.na(S.freq)[S.freq$freq!=0,])[[1]]
#[1] 4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`sum`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sum.html) to calculate the sum of integers. if NA's are found in your column you could be using `na.rm()`, however because the NA is located in a different column you first need to remove the row containing NA.

Our solution is as follows, we remove the rows containing NA by subsetting `S.freq[!is.na(S.freq$S),]`, but we also need the second column `freq`:

```
sum(S.freq[!is.na(S.freq$S), "freq"])
# 4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `na.omit` (to remove `NA`s) and `subset` ( to get rid off all lines in `freq` equal to 0):

```
subset(na.omit(S.freq), freq != 0)

   S freq
4  3    1
6  5    1
8  7    1
10 9    1
```

From here, that's straightforward:

```
length(subset(na.omit(S.freq), freq != 0)$freq)
[1] 4
```

Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for values with frequency > 0, that means you're looking for unique values. You get this information directly from vector S:

```
length(unique(df$S))
```

and leaving NA aside you get answer 4 by:

```
length(unique(df$S[!is.na(df$S)]))
```

Regarding your question on how to exclude a number of items based on their value:
In R this is easily done with logical vectors as you used it in you code already:

```
length(S.freq$freq[S.freq$freq!=0])
```

you can combine different conditions to one logical vector and use it for subsetting e.g.

```
length(S.freq$freq[S.freq$freq!=0 & !is.na(S.freq$freq)])
```

Comment: Unique fails if the frequency count is duplicated for two answers. Example length(unique(df$R[!is.na(df$R)]))
[1] 3
> df$R
[1]  5  5  7 NA  9

Comment: What would be your expected answer for vector df$R? You got the following frequencies 5: 2, 7: 1, NA: 1, 9: 1. Ommiting NA you have 3 values with frequency != 0

Comment: So you simply want to count the numbers of values which aren't NA? sum(!is.na(df$R)) would give you this result. But I don't see that in your original question

Comment: sum(!is.na(df$R)) gives the answer I'm looking for. The question relates to a transformed df with a frequency count of 0 or NA being excluded from length.

Comment: I found your answer sum(!is.na(df$R)) useful and elegant ... in fact I'm using it in my new script but it doesn't answer the question on how to exclude a number of items from a function based on the value which is essentially what the question asked.